# RegExp confusing behavior

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match next expression in PHP:

```
preg_match( '#<head>([\s\S]*)</head>#' , $this -> $html_file_content , $match );
```

with no success.

`$this -> $html_file_content` contains valid HTML code and the `<head>` block is not empty.

This regexp works just great in JavaScript.

I've already tried next variations:

```
#<head>([.\s\S]*)</head>#
#<head>([.\s\S]+)</head>#
#<head>([\s\S]*)<\/head>#
#<head>([\s\S]+)<\/head>#
```

All of them worked just fine in JavaScript. I just cannot figure out, why there is no match in PHP.

Could you, guys, help me handle it?

Comment: please also post the value of `$this -> $html_file_content`

Comment: general answer: you should not be using regexes to deal with html.

Comment: what does `var_dump($match);` give you? And you may consider adding `m` after the last `#` to make it match multi-line.

Comment: @MarcB Great comment in general. What is the best way?

Comment: use DOM: http://php.net/dom

Comment: @MarcB WOAH!!! You have just made my night!

Comment: @Jon var_dump shows an empty array and the flag didn't help

Comment: @MichaelSazonov haha, might be the `$this->$html_file_content`, as it should typically be `$this->html_file_content` (the last `$` removed from a class variable).  Other than that, you should use the DOM though. ^^

Comment: @Jon you are the hero! I could spend a year looking for this little mistake.

Comment: @MichaelSazonov It's a fairly easy mistake to make, especially if you aren't _that_ familiar with PHP classes. ^^

Comment: @Jon I am familiar with them, but mind mind went to France after hours of working, so there was no way for me to really see it.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: @MichaelSazonov haha, that is often the case as well.  =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this, so my guess is that `$this -> $html_file_content` should be

```
$this -> html_file_content
```

In case that doesn't work, maybe try it with `SimpleXML` assuming that the contents are well-formed.

```
$html = new SimpleXMLElement($html_file_content);
$head = "" . $html->head;
```

---

The common answer of "you should not use regex to parse HTML" is misguided.  As far as I can tell you're not trying to [*parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse) the HTML; you just want to extract a string value from known delimiters.  No one would have said anything if the delimiters were `[head]...[/head]`

Comment: Actually, your guess is correct. After writing for a whole day I just can't see such mistakes... The `$` sign should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

you say that there must be only on ore more space elemets but you need to have any text including spaces try this (.*?) i didn't try it but i hope this is the right

/(.*?)< /head>/

Comment: `.` will not match newlines without the `s` modifier

Comment: In fact, `[\s\S]*` matches all characters, including spacers